# Best practice to implement same HTML parser for several different website?

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I'm trying to code an HTML parser in C#. I need to get data from, let's say, 10 gambling website. I'm trying to figure out what is the best approach.
At first, I thought to write one big function that parse all of the websites with a switch statement, but I believe it's an overkill. It will be too long. I use HTML agility pack, so each implementation will have similar and yet different structure.

What is the best way to implement such a structure?

Comment: If the DOM structure of the websites is different how do you expect to achieve that with the same parser? You could have a base parser class which will retrieve the remote markup, feed it to HTML Agility Pack and then have some abstract method that will perform the actual selector to find the required DOM element. Then for each site you could have an implementation of this base class.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't quite understood what did you meant in your last sentence: what do you mean for each site? if I have 10 website, than I need 10 derived classes of that abstract class?

Comment: Yes, if their DOM structure is different.

Comment: One more question please. I know it's a noob question, but I must ask it nonetheless: what is the purpose of using an abstract class here? after all, I have 10 different methods right? the method in the abstract class does nothing really. Why can't I just declare a method with the same name to each one of my 10 classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a base class with the common parts and create a sub-class for each different parser. The functions that change from parser to parser can be declared as `abstract` so they have to be overridden in the different sub-classes.

Comment: Thanks. My thoughts exactly! :) I'm just thinking that in the future if I have more website to parse, I will have to modify the code..

Comment: You'll have to add another class to parse the new website.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern, it would be something along the lines of having an `Abstract` class (perhaps with some shared methods) that each `Concrete` class implements and overrides the `Abstract` method. Using a Factory method you could then select the appropriate Concrete class to call for parsing the HTML (perhaps depending on the Site URL or some configuration).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to go with that. Being a start simple guy, I'be be implementing one website / parser combination.
Then looking at what was common.
They all have a url.
They will all have some Parse thingy
And presumably you want to extract the same sort of information from each one.
And then you want to do something with that info.

That suggests a website class
A class to navigate through the website and get the page(s)
A parsing class
A parsing information class.

You could use inheritance, though my first thought was an interface.
Either way you should end up a with a collection of websites to parse, each one described by it's own instance.

From there you could simply do a foreach, you could schedule, you could do them in parallel. More to the point you could add and remove targets, keep going on the others when one of them twiddles with their site, or goes down...

Prove your idea with one site, your infrastructure with two, and batter away at the others, while having deployed something that works and see if anything happens in the real world that you hadn't thought of.

Big bangs are for making universes, not applications.